# How to display last missing element in an array that didn't exist in array

Tags: python, arrays

Original array: 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
Missing number in the array (10-20): 20.

```
arr = [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]
missing_elements = []
for ele in range(arr[0], arr[-1]+1):
    if ele not in arr:
        missing_elements.reverse(ele)
print(missing_elements)
```

i tried this many things but didn't get the answer its showing me empty array...!!

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([10,11,12,13,14,16,17,18,19,20])#missing 15
missing1=np.array([0 for i in range(len(arr)+1)],dtype=object)

for ele in range(10,20+1):
    if ele not in arr:
      print(ele)
arr1 = np.array([10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19])#missing 20
missing2=np.array([0 for i in range(len(arr1)+1)],dtype=object)

for ele in range(10,20+1):
    if ele not in arr1:
      print(ele)
```

this helps me. **Thank you everyone**

Comment: At what point do you `append` or `insert` items into `missing_elements`? If not at all, how is it supposed to be non-empty?

Comment: `[i for i in range(min(arr), max(arr)+2) if i not in arr]`?

Comment: More to the point, however, with your current code, your `range` doesn't include `20`, so you'll still get an empty list.

Comment: Following @Joshua's comments, if the `range` doesn't include the missing number, how are you expecting to detect it? Did you mean to write `arr[-1]+2`? Please [edit] to clarify. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: ```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([10,11,12,13,14,16,17,18,19,20])#missing 15
missing1=np.array([0 for i in range(len(arr)+1)],dtype=object)

for ele in range(10,20+1):
    if ele not in arr:
      print(ele)
arr1 = np.array([10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19])#missing 20
missing2=np.array([0 for i in range(len(arr1)+1)],dtype=object)

for ele in range(10,20+1):
    if ele not in arr1:
      print(ele)
```

this helps me.
i dont know how to add proper code in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your `range` doesn't include `20`, so as-is, your output will be empty even if you fix the `missing_elements.append` part.

---

Replace

```py
missing_elements.reverse(ele)
```

with

```py
missing_elements.append(ele)
```

and then

```py
print(missing_elements[-1])
```

Comment: the thing is that i have to print 20 that is missing between in the given array. when i try other codes it gives me an error that index out of range. my teacher asked me to print 20. and the array is from 10 to 19

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```py
arr = [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]
for ele in range(arr[0], arr[-1]+1):
    if ele not in arr:
        arr.append(ele)
print(arr[-1])
```

It adds the missing element then prints it out